How to see that "if the leading coefficient is 1 or -1, then the rational zeros must be factors of the constant term" in a polynomial
If p/q is a rational zero, in lowest terms, of a polynomial P, then to find its rational zero:
$$a_n(\frac{p}{q})^n + a_{n-1}(\frac{p}{q})^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1(\frac{p}{q}) + a_0 = 0 \therefore$$
$$\therefore \boxed{p(a_np^{n-1}+a_{n-1}p^{n-2}q+\cdots +a_1q^{n-1})=-a_0q^n}$$
I didn't quite understand when the book says that "if the leading coefficient is 1 or -1, then the rational zeros must be factors of the constant term."
Can anyone help me better understand how this really works?

To see that don't write it as in the second line. Write $a_np^n=q(...)$. Since $q$ and $p$ are relatively prime, then $q|a_n$. But if $a_n=\pm1$, then $q=\pm1$. In other words $p/q$ is an integer. Then use your second line $p(...)=-a_0q^n$. Since, $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, then $p|a_0$.

Welcome to Math SE. See Rational root theorem.

Rational root theorem is a very important theorem. Try a small example with 2 known roots. Construct the polynomial and see the similarity of your example and the abstract expression above. You also need to understand the concept of writing a number as a product of prime factors.
